# Storing unworn shoes for years

Tags: clothing, storage, shoes

I have a pair of shoes from Crocs that I like the design of, and am thinking of getting a second pair in case they get discontinued or significantly altered.

Does anyone have ideas/experience for storing unworn Crocs properly? [This](https://tt.tennis-warehouse.com/index.php?threads/can-i-store-shoes-for-years.341686/) link says that you can sometimes use ziplock bags, silica gel, or a combination to store some shoes, but I'm not sure if they apply for whatever crocs are made of.

Comment: Soles made of Contura (not to my knowledge used by Crocs) will degrade over time and go brittle.

Comment: Have you considered buying N pairs and wearing them in rotation?

Comment: Is it better to do them in rotation or to keep one pristine while the other gets used? Either way, I'd prefer to keep one pair in mint condition because I don't exactly know when I'll replace/use them.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I have not made good experiences storing shoes from materials like crocs.

As far as I know crocs are made from croslite which is a type of [EVA foam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethylene-vinyl_acetate), which is a similar to the material shoe soles or flip flops are made of.

From my experience, this material is ageing worse when not regularly in use. It might sound counterintuitive, but the longer you store your shoes the more brittle the material becomes (even if you shield it from extreme temperatures and direct sunlight).

I think this effect is most known to occasional hikers who find their soles falling off or crumbling apart on the first few miles after they stored their boots for a couple of months/years.

So regularly wearing your crocs for a few hours a month might increase their longevity. Although I don't know if crocs has added something to their patented EVA foam to prevent this from happening.

Hope this helps and good luck as well :)

Answer (score 0):

**Storing unworn shoes for years!**

Stored shoes for several years, including crooks!

I placed them in an ordinary shoe box, which I wrote type of shoes were in the actual shoe box.

If you do this, simply add a few [moisture absorption sachets](https://www.uline.ca/BL_1008/String-Sewn-Desiccants) to the contents of your shoe box. The box will help the shoes (crocs) from getting deformed. There are many type of moisture absorption sachets on the market. Anyone of them are fine. I get mine fine a local shopping mall.

The main thing is keep them dry and out of extreme temperatures.

A few days prior to using them, I would treat them with an [Armor All](https://www.armorall.com/expert-tips/exterior-tips/plastic-rubber-vinyl-canvas) product to help prevent any possible cracking that may occur due to a prolonged storage! This is what I do.

Good luck.

Comment: I also have stored shoes for years with little degradation. If the shoes are made of synthetics, high temperatures or sunlight causes volitiles to evaporate from rubber or plastic sole material, and make them brittle. Nylon-like materials (non-sole parts of shoes) are more durable. Natural materials (hemp/cotton) are more durable but risk insects or mice eating the materials.  Storing shoes in original boxes in my closet prevents any problems for me. Airtight bag storage won't help unless you live in unusually humid area. Armor All counteracts lost volitiles from brittle plastics.